# How to shift number by a given number of bits in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

If I were told to shift left 1 by x bits where x is stored in r1. Is the instruction lsls r1,#1 or do I store the value 1 (say in r2) and then shift it using lsls r2,r1. I want to confirm if either of these are correct - the 2nd option seems to make more sense.

Comment: Yes, the second option. You can consult the instruction set reference and of course try it in a debugger.

Comment: Look at compiler output: https://godbolt.org/z/rnhG7K9s1 shows Thumb mode for `return 1U << x;`.  You're correct that you can't `mov` an immediate 1 left-shifted by a register all in one instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you're working in ARM or thumb. You're working in Thumb so use @Jester 's answer for Thumb. For 32-bit ARM, you would use

```
        mov    r1, #1
        lsl  r0, r1, r0
```

For shifting a register left by 1, you would use:

```
        MOV R1,R1,LSL #1
```

Comment: The question is asking how to do `1 << r1`, not `r1 << 1`.  https://godbolt.org/z/rnhG7K9s1

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry I misread the question.

Comment: You're now claiming that you should use `lsl.w` in ARM mode. That's a Thumb instruction; you can tell by the `.w`.   (Unless you mean for ARM as opposed to AArch64?).  Also, you don't need to leave in the part about how you had the question backwards earlier.  You can just say "contrast this to shifting a register left by 1" to introduce your other code block.  Future readers don't need to go on this journey of how you misread the question, that's irrelevant.  Edit your answer to be in the best shape for people who click on this question next week / month / year.

Comment: Hmm, it showed me 
```movs    r1, #1 lsl  r0, r1, r0```
even after removing ```-mthumb``` from the compiler instructions. I thought that was strange but I'm not sure why

Comment: Thumb is the default for most CPUs because (with Thumb2) it's often more efficient.  Use `-marm` and it will pick `mov  r1, #1` instead of `movs` for the first instruction, because the flag-setting version only saves space in thumb mode.

Comment: I see. ARM isn't exactly my forte, I'm only familiar with ARMv4.